# Explorer.exe using 10% CPU constantly

Tags: windows, cpu, windows-explorer, cpu-usage

I searched the internet for any clues, but unfortunately they were mostly related to SHcore or ntoskrnl and I think my sample is kind of different. After some time of using the PC explorer.exe goes nuts and is hogging 10% of my CPU, additionally making the system much less responsive. After restarting explorer.exe it's getting fixed, but I am really tired of restarting it few times a day every day.

I tried to analyze it with Process Hacker, but I have no idea where the problem is. It's not idle problem, nor some kind of cryptocurrency mining virus. I am using a 2 monitor setup, but IIRC the problem started a year ago when I upgraded my i5-2500k to Ryzen 5 3600.

Process Hacker:

[image: Screenshot from Process Hacker]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Does it happen within Safe Mode?

Comment: Explorer is a tricky one.  ANYONE can create a shell extension and extend it with 3rd party code (if you allow that extension to be installed).  That makes determining causes difficult at best.  There are free utilities on the net that will show you what has been added to your explorer.  I would guess that your CPU grind is being caused by a third party extension.

Comment: when you have it run from an admin prompt: `wpr.exe -start GeneralProfile`.  Leave this for 30 seconds and then run `wpr.exe -stop C:\gp.etl` Open this with Windows Performance Analyzer which you can get from the Store or by downloading the ADK/SDK. Focus on the CPU sampled view to start.